# Azure Mobile Service Query top ten results

Tags: c#, linq, azure

I want to return the top 10 items in each group of items that I have stored in an Azure Mobile Service table.

```
IE._qryItemResult = _tblResult
                      .Where(item => item.grouptype == 1)
                      .Take(10)
                      .ToEnumerableAsync();
```

If I then want the top 10 items with grouptype=2 and so on... do I need to execute another query and append to the initial result or am I missing a cleverer way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many entries does your _tblResult contain ? If it's not a significant amount, you could just bring the lot back into memory, and then use linq queries on them there.

But if you have to go out to the service each time, then yes you will need to specify multiple seperate queries, each with their own `Where()` filter/`Take()` amount combo.

Comment: At the moment its only 530 records - but it has the potential to grow. I guess its down to me to test with x amount of records to see at what point performance looks to be impacted and manage things accordingly. I will use memory for now as you suggest - and mark as answer.